# How to understand this regex that searches Yahoo Finance?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, yahoo-finance

I'm searching for this string in the Yahoo Finance web page source
`"CrumbStore":{"crumb":"abcdEFGHijklm"}`

I understand that the following code compiles a regex that searches for the string above and assigns it to pattern

```
pattern = re.compile('.*"CrumbStore":\{"crumb":"(?P<crumb>[^"]+)"\}')
```

I need to understand what `'.*` does?

Also, the `\`.

Also the `(?P<crumb>[^"]+)"\}'`

Comment: See explanation here - https://regex101.com/r/O7f0qW/2

Comment: Go to www.regular-expression.info and read the tutorial. `.` is one of the most basic regular expression operators.

Comment: You need an explanation for the quotes at the beginning and end of the string, too?

Comment: Thanks for the signposting. Will do

Comment: I've learned so much by following your excellent suggestions. I am v grateful to both of you